# C++ structure for time with TZ, but without date?

Tags: c++, c++-chrono

Are there any structures in the C++ std::chrono spec to represent a time, along with a time zone, but without the date? The issue is that I want to be able to filter records which have unix time (time_t), and return all records which have times between "10:00 EST" and "11:00 EST". This would require converting the time_t to EST, stripping the time, and then comparing it to a "time" structure.

Comment: Timezones are defined separately from the daylight savings.  The chromo uses the IANA listings, and both EST and EDT are "America/New_York".  You cannot know the daylight savings in this scheme without also having the date.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono

Comment: This looks like XY question. You are asking about some structure in some library, yet you _really_ search for an efficient and simple way for filtering `time_t` values between specified hours range. Is that "structure in the C++ std::chrono" you are searching for anyhow related to the other problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++20 introduces time zone support for chrono.  It isn't shipping yet, but there's a [free, open-source preview library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).  It does require some [installation for the time zone support](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation).

There is no ready made data-structure for `{time-of-day, time_zone}`.  However you could easily build your own by storing time-of-day as a `chrono::duration` (say `seconds`?) and a `chrono::time_zone const*` (`date::time_zone const*` in the [preview lib](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date)).

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

struct my_event
{
    date::time_zone const* tz;
    std::chrono::seconds tod;
};

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const my_event& e)
{
    return os << date::format("%T ", e.tod) << e.tz->name();
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;

    time_t t = 1609186734;
    zoned_time zt{"America/New_York", sys_seconds{seconds{t}}};
    auto local_time = zt.get_local_time();
    auto tz = zt.get_time_zone();
    my_event e{tz, local_time - floor<days>(local_time)};
    cout << e << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
15:18:54 America/New_York
```

Comment: Looks good, the only thing missing would be library functions, which i guess i could write, that would take a time_t, convert to a zoned date/time then compare the times.

Comment: Yeah, it's a one-liner as shown above.  Though that does assume `time_t` is seconds of Unix Time, which POSIX specifies but C doesn't.  If you really want to get paranoid you can pass it through `system_clock::from_time_t()` instead.  Comparing times is just using `operator<` on `my_event.tod` and your [begin, end] limits.

Answer (score 0):

The C library function `localtime` (which is perfectly usable in C++ code) takes a (pointer to a) `time_t` and returns a (pointer to a) `struct tm` that has both date and time values.

However there is no law that says that you must use the date parts of it, in some fashion. You are free to ignore them and look at only the hour, minute, and second values.

Answer (score 0):

At least in my opinion, Howard Hinnant has given pretty much the correct answer here (and if he weren't quite so modest, he'd probably have pointed out that he defined and implemented much of the addition to the standard he mentions).

In particular, to determine the time of day (at least as most places figure things) we have to first figure up the day of the year, since many (most?) places change the clocks by an hour a couple of times a year (an hour forward sometime in the spring, an hour back sometime in the fall). So, to do the job right, we have essentially no choice but to take dates into account.

For the moment, let's assume we can ignore that change in time. While we're at it, let's also assume we have a POSIX-like time_t (i.e., one that's an integer count of seconds since midnight, first of January 1970. And since most people pay them little  mind anyway, I'm going to also assume we can ignore the leap seconds that have been inserted since 1970 (27 of them, if I'm not mistaken).

In this case, we can simply treat a day as 24 hours. 24 hours/day * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute gives us 86'400 seconds/day. So, some_time_t % 86'400 gives us an offset (in seconds) into the day.

10 AM is 10 hours past midnight, so it's an offset of 10 hours * 60 minutes/hour * 60 seconds/minute = 36'000 seconds. 11 AM is 11 hours * 60 * 60 = 39'600 seconds.

So, for this drastically simplified model of time, we simplify the question down to:

```cpp
bool in_range(time_t input) { 

    int offset = input % 86'400;

    return offset >= 36'000 && offset < 39'600;
}
```

In theory, you could add at least a few factors back in that we've intentionally ignored up to this point--leap seconds would be pretty easy, as long as you don't mind updating a config file (or something on that order) any time another leap second gets inserted. Compensating for daylight savings time/summer time would be fairly easy in some ways. Basically compute an offset of seconds into a year for when the clock shifts happen, and (much like above) compute seconds % seconds/year to get an offset of seconds into a year, then compare it to the offsets when clock shifts happen.

But, since you've specified `EST` in general, I'm going to guess that (for whatever reason) you don't care about seasonal time changes.

But I'll repeat: I'd think of this solely as an intellectual exercise in something that (under just the right circumstances, with the right simplifying assumptions) could work, not as something that actually does or will work. Howard's answer is really the right way to deal with this.

Comment: I do care about getting the “zoned” time from a time_t though. The issue is I have records which store a time_t (UTC), and I want to find all records between two zoned times. ie taking into account leaps, DST, etc.

Comment: To clarify, lets say you have records covering 5 years, and you want all of the records which have a America/Eastern time between 17:00 and 18:00, regardless of the date. Would want to be able to also run the same filter for 17:00 to 18:00 America/Central, as well if the user specified central.

Comment: @bpeikes: That's purely a matter of adjusting the begin/end offsets. EST is UTC-5, so 17:00 EST is 23:00 EST.